# How to get values from EditText from a different Class in android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

This is not the usual question everyone else has asked, I know how to get the value from `EditText`. I am creating a login/signup for my app, I want to have the user login data retrieved by one separate class/package and the user sign up data with a separate class/package. NOTE: this Class is not an activity but does extend `AppCompatActivity` to allow the use of `findViewById`.

This is the UserSignUpData.class with just one `get-Method` as it crashes start after

```
public class UserSignUpData extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String getSignUpFullName() {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_name); //NullPointerException
        String fn = et.getText().toString();
        return fn;
    }//end getSignUpFullName()
```

And I am calling the `onClick(signup)` method that I declared in the layout from the MainActivity.class like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void signUp(View v){
       UserSignUpData signUpData = new UserSignUpData();
       String name = signUpData.getSignUpFullName();
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ud.getSignUpFullName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       //just to test if it works
    }
```

So I end up getting a NullPointerException which points to

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_name);
```

This is the error code:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:72)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
     at com.example.pc_charlie.loginapp.UserSignUpData.getSignUpFullName(UserSignUpData.java:12)
     at com.example.pc_charlie.loginapp.MainActivity.signUp(MainActivity.java:52)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I could also be wrong about it being a NullPointerException, but its some error thats stopping the code from working. thanks

Comment: "does extend AppCompatActivity to allow the use of findViewById" -- I don't think you understand how `findViewById` works. You can't find views across  other activities just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is not for an `Activity`. You should not extend activity.

I'm assuming you are trying to separate out the logic into another class.

In that case just pass the EditText as a parameter to the method `getSignUpFullName` as `getSignUpFullName(EditText et)` after instantiating it properly in the MainActivity. Do not try to find it in the `UserSignUpData` class.

Comment: That worked mate thanks :) I just got of a Java Spring project, so im still thinking in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just trying to pass data between classes. You don't need to find a view from a separate class, and a "data container" class probably shouldn't extend any Activity.

```
public class UserSignUpData {

    private String signUpFullName;

    public UserSignUpData(String fullName) {
        this.signUpFullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getSignUpFullName() { return this.signUpFullName };
}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void signUp(View v){
       EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_name);
       String name = et.getText().toString();

       UserSignUpData ud = new UserSignUpData(name);
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ud.getSignUpFullName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       //just to test if it works
    }
}
```